# Does sed's multiline Next Line (N) have a limit?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm using sed to match multiple lines.

```
me@CYGWIN:$ cat foo.txt
Click on <menucascade>
        <uicontrol>File</uicontrol>
        <uicontrol>Save</uicontrol>
        <uicontrol>Options</uicontrol>
        <uicontrol>PDF</uicontrol>
</menucascade>.
```

I want sed to:

1. Look for the menucascade tag.
2. Change the following uicontrol tags to b tags.
3. Add a > to the end of the line.
4. Do this only when uicontrol comes within menucascade (and not
   any other time).

If I know the number of times that uicontrol is used, I can use N to add the next line to the pattern space:

```
me@CYGWIN:$ sed '/<menucascade>/{N;N;N;N; s/<uicontrol>\([^<]*\)<\/uicontrol>/<b>\1<\/b>\ >/g}' foo.txt
Click on <menucascade>
        <b>File</b> >
        <b>Save</b> >
        <b>Options</b> >
        <b>PDF</b> >
</menucascade>.
```

But what if I don't know the number of times uicontrol is used (and therefore don't know the number of N's to add)? On Cygwin, sed seems to max out after 5 N's. Thus if I overestimate, and put in more than 5 N's, it doesn't work at all.

```
me@CYGWIN:$ sed '/<menucascade>/{N;N;N;N;N;N; s/<uicontrol>\([^<]*\)<\/uicontrol>/<b>\1<\/b>\ >/g}' foo.txt
Click on <menucascade>
        <uicontrol>File</uicontrol>
        <uicontrol>Save</uicontrol>
        <uicontrol>Options</uicontrol>
        <uicontrol>PDF</uicontrol>
</menucascade>.
```

First: can anyone explain why the sed script fails to match with 6 N's?

Second: Can anyone suggest how to match n number of instances of uicontrol within menucascade using sed? Or, if sed is the wrong tool, can anyone suggest an alternative that works in a bash script?

Thanks.

Comment: use something like `sed '/<menucascade>/,/<\/menucascade>/ {#Your code for the section here;}'`

Comment: Nullifiying the downvote. This is a valid questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `N` as many times as you want, but (from POSIX):

> If no next line of input is available, the N command verb shall branch to the end of the script

So if just use them carelessly, eventually they'll cause your script to end.

POSIX also does not guarantee more than 8192 bytes in the pattern space, but you're probably using GNU sed which supports way more.

The correct way of doing this is with an xml tool like `xmlstarlet`, though this assumes you're using at least a semblance of xhtml:

```
$ cat foo.xml
<html>
    <h1>Blah</h1>
    <p>
      Click on <menucascade>
      <uicontrol>File</uicontrol>
      <uicontrol>Save</uicontrol>
      <uicontrol>Options</uicontrol>
      <uicontrol>PDF</uicontrol>
      </menucascade>
    </p>
    <p>
      <uicontrol>Other stuff</uicontrol>
    </p>
</html>
```

then

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -r "//menucascade/uicontrol" -v b foo.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
  <h1>Blah</h1>
  <p>
      Click on <menucascade><b>File</b><b>Save</b><b>Options</b><b>PDF</b></menucascade>
    </p>
  <p>
    <uicontrol>Other stuff</uicontrol>
  </p>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, that explains why it was failing. Thanks!